# auto updating without duplicate content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have created a shortcode which basically outputs a list of match results. These match results is being parsed by a JSON script which is connected to a cron job on the server to update every 5 minute. Instead of people refreshing browser themself i was wondering how it i can be able to update this automatically using AJAX, Jquery and not duplicating the matches?

the short code looks like following:

```
[resultpage]
```

Shortcode function:

```
function resultpage() {



    $output = '';



    $output .= '<div id="content">';
        $output .= '<div id="part-1">';

        $output .= getgames("lol");


        $output .= '</div>';
       $output .= ' <div id="part-2">';
       $output .= getgames("counterstrike");
       $output .= ' </div>';
       $output .= ' <div id="part-3">';
       $output .= getgames("dota2");
       $output .= ' </div>';
       $output .= ' <div id="part-4">';
       $output .= getgames("hearthstone");
       $output .= ' </div>';
    $output .= '</div>';




return $output;
}
```

getGames function

```
function getgames($thegame) {
$json = file_get_contents('JSON URL');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$livegames = $obj->live;  


$output = '';

foreach($livegames as $live){



        if ($live->game == $thegame) {
            $teamarray = returnteam($live->{'team 1'}->name, $live->{'team 2'}->name);

        if ($live->{'team 1'}->score == "") {
            $score1 = '0';
        }else {
            $score1 = $live->{'team 1'}->score;
        }
        if ($live->{'team 2'}->score == "") {
            $score2 = '0';
        } else {
            $score2 = $live->{'team 2'}->score;
        }



        $output .= '<div class="result-in-month">';

        $output .= '<div class="result-date">';
        $output .= $live->{'live in'};
        $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="result-match-team-wrapper">';
                    $output .= '<span class="result-match-team left">';
                        $output .= $teamarray[0];

                    $output .= '</span>';
                    $output .= '<span class="result-match-versus">';
                        $output .= '<span class="result-match-score">'. $score1 .'</span><span class="result-match-separator">-</span><span class="result-match-score">'. $score2 .'</span>';
                    $output .= '</span>';
                    $output .= '<span class="result-match-team right">';
                    $output .= $teamarray[1];

                    $output .= '</span>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="result-stream">';
                $output .= '<a href="'. $live->{'streams'}[0] .'">';
                $output .= 'Stream';
                $output .= '</a>';
                $output .= '</div>';

            $output .= '<div class="clear"></div>';

        $output .= '</div>';

    }
    }
}
```

Sample data

```
{
    "live": [
    {
        "match_id": "65551",
        "has_vods": false,
        "game": "hearthstone",
        "team 1": {
            "score": "",
            "name": "ViCi Gaming",
            "bet": "39%"
        },
        "team 2": {
            "score": "",
            "name": "ZhanQi TV",
            "bet": "61%"
        },
        "live in": "Live",
        "title": "ViCi Gaming... 39% vs 61% ZhanQi TV",
        "url": "",
        "tounament": "http://www.gosugamers.net/",
        "simple_title": "ViCi Gaming... vs ZhanQi TV",
        "streams": [
            "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=Curemew"
        ]
    },
    {
        "match_id": "64907",
        "has_vods": false,
        "game": "dota2",
        "team 1": {
            "score": "",
            "name": "Summoner's Rift",
            "bet": "19%"
        },
        "team 2": {
            "score": "",
            "name": "Thundercats!",
            "bet": "12%"
        },
        "live in": "Live",
        "title": "Summoner's Rift 19% vs 12% Thundercats!",
        "url": "",
        "tounament": "http://www.gosugamers.net/",
        "simple_title": "Summoner's Rift vs Thundercats!",
        "streams": [
            "http://www.majorleaguegaming.com/player/embed/joinDOTA?autoplay=0"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What does `getGames` output look like? Do you store post data in any attributes? What have you done to implement the ajax? Question is very broad.

Comment: i've added the getgames function. Which basically just loop divs which contain game info.

Comment: Well if you don't want duplicates need a way to know what is already in the page by assigning some id or timestamp as a data attribute. Also, how do you track what goes in json file? or is it a php script that connects to db? Too many unknowns here

Comment: I've created a api which scrapes data and place it into a JSON file and every 5 minute when the cron job is running in the server the json script is updated. Every match has a match id which can be accesed by $live->match_id. i've just not used it since i do not have much experience with the likes of AJAX and Jquery.

Comment: Well i don't really see how using a json file will work very well. A db table would likely be better. Unless the data will only have a very short lifespan and you plan to overwrite the file regularly

Comment: the JSON file is being replaced every 5 minutes, but every match has an id in the JSON file, so u could be able to identify each match by that i guess?

Comment: ok, so I doubt the file is very big. Use some data attributes that hold the id's and you can check the highest ones before updating the html

Comment: Could u provide an answer with a snippet or so which could lead in the right direction, i'm not strong with AJAX and Jquery. best regards.

Comment: provide a data sample that can be used for demo

Comment: I've added some sample data.

Comment: Here's a very rough starting concept that runs every 4 seconds fro demo purposes  http://plnkr.co/edit/1oi6cv9OP7oPTRAZ0vL1?p=preview

Comment: Nice however it does not seem to update the score if some of the key changes for instance "live in" or "score"

Comment: not sure what that means

Comment: If you look in the json script every match has a score and a live in key. These will change, so if these change it also needs to update.

Comment: then you should just replace them all probably